# Preencher dados da view base apenas uma vez

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma *view* base que possui um vários *dropdowns* que dependem de valores do banco de dados, denominando ela como "base.blade.php".

Também possuo várias outras views que estendem dessa base, como por exemplo: `depoimentos.blade.php`, `contato.blade.php` e etc. Dessa forma, as views precisam ter esses dropdowns, assim como possuem seus próprios dados, além dos dados necessários na view base, para que no DepoimentosController, ContatosController e etc, possa passa os dados da própria view e da view base.

Mas a suponha que eu tenha mais 10 outras páginas, terei que adicionar os dados da view base em todos os controllers.

Existe alguma outra maneira de eu preencher os dados da view base uma vez só?

Comment: de uma olhada nesse manual do lara https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

Comment: Eu acabei resolvendo utilizando view composer do laravel, obrigado!